# configuring yeoman for ubuntu 14.04 grunt command wont work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gruntjs, yeoman

I get the following when i try to use grunt, yo, bower ect

no error just next line ive installed every dependancy i can think of so i dunno what else to check
below is from my terminal

Any ideas

```
justin@justinComputer:~/Documents/gitRepos/gitRepo2$ cd learningAngular/
justin@justinComputer:~/Documents/gitRepos/gitRepo2/learningAngular$ grunt serve
justin@justinComputer:~/Documents/gitRepos/gitRepo2/learningAngular$ grunt serve
justin@justinComputer:~/Documents/gitRepos/gitRepo2/learningAngular$ grunt serve
justin@justinComputer:~/Documents/gitRepos/gitRepo2/learningAngula
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm install` inside your `learningAngular` directory. And then `grunt serve`.